# Simple program not working in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm

```
.386
.model flat, c
.stack 100 h
.data

num1    sdword ?
num2    sdword ?
        .code
main    proc
        mov num1,5
        mov eax,num1
        mov num2,eax
        ret
main    endp
        end
```

I have checked the masm in the build customization of the project.

I have changed the item type to Microsoft Macro Assembler.

But, it is still showing error messages below:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   A2206   missing operator in expression  testing C:\Users\Kin\Desktop\assembly\testing\testing\Source.asm    3   
Error   A2206   missing operator in expression  testing C:\Users\Kin\Desktop\assembly\testing\testing\Source.asm    2   
Error   MSB3721 The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\Source.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /TaSource.asm" exited with code 1.    testing H:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets 50
```

---

Changed to .stack 100h
It is now showing:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  testing C:\Users\Kin\Desktop\assembly\testing\Debug\testing.exe 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _WinMainCRTStartup   testing C:\Users\Kin\Desktop\assembly\testing\testing\LINK  1
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between `100` and `h`, It should be `100h`

Comment: Oh! thanks Micahel
But it showing: 
Error LNK1120 1 unresolved externals 
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _WinMainCRTStartup

Comment: You'll have to redefine the entry point for the code. Seems you created a Win32 Windows application. Changing the entry point is as easy as placing the new entry point label on the end of the `end` directive. The very last line that says `end` should be `end main`